# How to convert WhoId to text in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, administration, fields

I've to check whether the `WhoId` value is Contact or Lead. If I convert `WhoId` to text then I can check if by standard object prefix like '003' for Contact. So is there any possible way to convert `WhoId` to Text in formula fields?

I tried with the formula:

```
IF( BEGINS(TEXT(WhoID), 003),'Contact','Lead' )
```

which produces the error:

> Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected Number, Date, DateTime, Picklist, received Lookup(Contact,Lead)

Comment: Have you considered simply using `Who.Type`? Where are you consuming this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WhoId` rather than `Who.Id`. Don't wrap it in the `TEXT` function either. **The value is an Id which behaves as text already.** This formula passes a syntax check just fine:

```
CASE(
    LEFT(WhoId, 3),
    "003", "Contact",
    "00Q", "Lead",
    ""
)
```

Please note if you are trying to access this data via SOQL, you do not even need a formula. You can query or filter on `Who.Type`.

```
SELECT count() FROM Task WHERE Who.Type = 'Lead'
```